# Kotlin / Firebase / Android Studio- java.util.NoSuchElementException: List is empty

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I made an application like Instagram and everything works fine, except when new user create a profile, the application stops/crash because it doesn't have anything to show on the home page and it drops `java.util.NoSuchElementException: List is empty.

here is the full error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.homeactivity, PID: 14508
java.util.NoSuchElementException: List is empty.
    at kotlin.collections.CollectionsKt___CollectionsKt.first(_Collections.kt:196)
    at com.example.homeactivity.activities.MainActivity$onStart$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:61)
    at com.example.homeactivity.activities.MainActivity$onStart$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:30)
    at com.example.homeactivity.utils.ValueEventListenerAdapter.onDataChange(ValueEventListenerAdapter.kt:13)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:75)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

here is MainActivity.kt line 51-66

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    val currentUser = mFirebase.auth.currentUser
    if(currentUser == null){
        startActivity(Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java))
        finish()
    } else {
        mFirebase.database.child("feed-posts").child(currentUser.uid)
            .addValueEventListener(ValueEventListenerAdapter { it ->
                val posts = it.children.map { it.getValue(FeedPost::class.java)!! }
                Log.d(TAG, "feedPosts: ${posts.first().timestampDate()}")
                feed_recycler.adapter = FeedAdapter(posts)
                feed_recycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
            })
    }
}
```

MainActivity.kt line 30-32

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity(0) {
private val TAG = "MainActivity"
private lateinit var mFirebase: FirebaseHelper
```

ValueEventListenerAdapter.kt line 8-19

```
    class ValueEventListenerAdapter(val handler: (DataSnapshot) -> Unit): ValueEventListener {
        private val TAG = "ValueEventListenerAdapt"

        override fun onDataChange(data: DataSnapshot) {
           handler(data)
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
           Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled: ", error.toException())
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You try to get element using `first` from empty list. Try to remove this

```
//Log.d(TAG, "feedPosts: ${posts.first().timestampDate()}")
```

Instead try to use `firstOrNull` like below:

```
Log.d(TAG, "feedPosts: ${posts.firstOrNull()?.timestampDate()}")
```